# Problema con datos dinamicos en mi web

Tags: web, api, aplicación-web

Buenos días,

Tengo un problema y es que mi web tiene unos datos que se actualizan con un contador a través de una api que proporciona los datos y si pongo www.xxxx no me carga los datos pero sin el www. si que me los carga correctamente.

Que puedo mirar o hacer?

Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Estas usando Apache?
prueba a hacer que Apache redirecciones automáticamente tu sitio.
Estas lineas deberian incluirlas en un archivo .htaccess en la raiz de tu espacio publico.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xxxx.com [NC]
```

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.xxxx.com/$1[L,R=301]`

Comment: Esto redireccionara el www a la de sin www no? Gracias!

Comment: He añadido las lineas que me comentaste y me da error.

Comment: Te fijaste que tienes que reemplazar "xxxx" por tu dominio?
solo la "xxxx",    el resto del código queda tal cueal.   
prueba tambien a hacer la operación imversa con esto:


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xxxx\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.xxxx\.com$